# Movie where an object is recovered from space and brought back to earth

Tags: story-identification

When no one is looking it starts to assemble either itself or other robot creatures from objects found around the room.

This is **NOT** one of the recent Transformer movies, it probably dates back to the 80's as I rented it on VHS.

Comment: [Virus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120458/)?

Comment: I don't think so, the plot doesn't seem familiar and perhaps too recent. I'll track it down and watch it though, just in case.

Comment: [Moontrap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/)?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it !!! I'll see if I can get it somewhere. Thanks !

Comment: Full movie linked below. You may also find [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46412/what-obstacles-legal-or-otherwise-prevent-moontrap-1989-from-being-released) to be of interest.

Comment: @Tim - Don't forget to mark the answer below as "accepted"

Answer (score 8):

This is [Moontrap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911)

> During a routine flight, two veteran space shuttle pilots discover an
>   alien artifact and bring it back to earth. It soon turns out to be an
>   extraterrestrial war robot, which is able to recycle any biological or
>   technical material for its own deadly use. The two astronauts are sent
>   to the moon, where Nasa expects to uncover the mystery of the alien
>   robot's origin. They discover an ancient humanoid culture and battle
>   the ultimate threat of the war machines heading to earth.

Comment: For the record, this film is *awful*. I think the sole reason anyone should see it is so that no matter how bad the film they're watching is, they can always think to themselves "***At least I'm not watching Moontrap again***"

Comment: No. It must be seen to support the career of the greatest actor of his generation, Bruce Campbell!

Comment: There is a DVD version available, or at least my library had a copy.

Comment: @Richard Do you think it would work even if one were watching *Batman and Robin* or *The Bachelor*?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - It works on all occasion, except if one is watching [Starcrash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/), at which point you'll *yearn* for the subtle artistry of Moontrap.